# getting error while using insert and delete query simultaneously in jsp

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

i m getting some errors ,i m trying to insert some data into a table in mysql db and also want to delete some data from another table simultaneously. i am using jsp,jdbc. i can't understand why i am getting this error, here is the code for my jsp page..

else{
               String sql1;

```
        try{


            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,passwd);

            String s1=request.getParameter("myText");
            String s2=request.getParameter("myText1");
            String s3=request.getParameter("myText2");
            String s4=request.getParameter("myText3");
            String s5=request.getParameter("myText4");
            String s6=request.getParameter("myText5");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date issueDate = sdf.parse(s4);
            Date expiryDate=sdf.parse(s5);
            sql="insert into library.issue values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps.setString(1,s1);
            ps.setString(2,s2);
            ps.setString(3,s3);
            ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(issueDate.getTime()));
            ps.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(expiryDate.getTime()));
            ps.setString(6,s6);
            ps.addBatch(sql);
            sql1="delete from library.books where book_id=?";
            ps.setString(1,s3);
            ps.addBatch(sql1);
            int[] count=ps.executeBatch();
            con.commit();
            response.sendRedirect("complete.jsp");



        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            try{
                con.rollback();
            }catch(SQLException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }finally{
            try{
                if(ps!=null ){
                    ps.close();

                }
            }catch(SQLException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                if(con!=null ){
                    con.close();

                }
            }catch(SQLException e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
    %>
```

and i am getting the following errors..

java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1695)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3020)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1008)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ServerPreparedStatement.java:582)
    at org.apache.jsp.reaction2_jsp._jspService(reaction2_jsp.java:201)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

library is my db name and issue is my tablename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot combine different SQL statements in `PreparedStatement` batch. So either use normal `Statement`, or two `PreparedStatement`s in one transaction.

Comment: hello jozef , first of all thnx for the reply , i actually tried what u suggested me but now it executing only first sql query nd second is throwing some exception . here is the exception..      sql.SQLException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`library`.`issue`, CONSTRAINT `issue_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`book_id`)).   can u tell me the reason please?

Comment: now code works successfully...thnx buddy,  there was a little foriegn key issue that i have resolved.